# Когда сворачиваешь приложение onLocationChanged перестает обновлять значение в Service

Tags: java, android

Создаю Service который обновляет геолокацию, когда сворачиваю приложение перестает срабатывать этот метод onLocationChanged, как можно обратно запустить обновления геолокации?

```
<service
            android:name=".GPSTrackerService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:stopWithTask="false"
            android:exported="true">
        </service>
```

```
public class GPSTrackerService extends Service implements  LocationListener{

    private static final long MINIMUM_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 1; // in Meters
    private static final long MINIMUM_TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES = 1000; // in Milliseconds

    protected LocationManager locationManager;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        startLoc();
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    private void startLoc() {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        }
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                MINIMUM_TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES,
                MINIMUM_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES,
                new GPSTrackerService()
        );
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(){
        super.onCreate();
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
            startMyOwnForeground();
        else
            startForeground(1, new Notification());
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    private void startMyOwnForeground(){
        String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "com.example.simpleapp";
        String channelName = "My Background Service";
        NotificationChannel chan = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, channelName, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_NONE);
        chan.setLightColor(Color.BLUE);
        chan.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PRIVATE);
        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        assert manager != null;
        manager.createNotificationChannel(chan);

        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);
        Notification notification = notificationBuilder.setOngoing(true)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark)
                .setContentTitle("App is running in background")
                .setPriority(NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_MIN)
                .setCategory(Notification.CATEGORY_SERVICE)
                .build();
        startForeground(2, notification);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(@NonNull Location location) {
        String message = String.format(
                    "New Location \n Longitude: %1$s \n Latitude: %2$s",
                    location.getLongitude(), location.getLatitude()
            );
            System.out.println(message);
    }

}
```

Comment: Какой андроид на эмуляторе?

Comment: @ArtyMorris Использую Android 11

Comment: в настройки андроида заходи, разрешения приложения, использовать всегда доступ к местоположению. В 11 андроиде в фоне по умолчанию не работает. так же в программе надо при запросе разрешений указать уже новый запрос

Comment: оф док в помощь https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background-location-limits

Answer (score 0):

Определение геолокации не работает в фоновом режиме Android 10 (уровень API 29) и выше, для разрешения в манифесте надо добавить
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />`

Answer (score 0):

В манифесте прописать:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
//У меня геолокация в сервисе прописана
<service
   android:name=".MainService" 
   android:enabled="true"
   android:foregroundServiceType="location"
   android:exported="true"
   android:stopWithTask="false">
</service>
```

Далее в Activity

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // разрешение не предоставлено
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_GPS);
        }
    } else {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // разрешение не предоставлено
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_GPS);
        }
    }
```

Наслаждаться